# How to build the Vue Hello World project with vue/require-direct-export

Tags: vuejs2

Just started with Vue, and install the HelloWorld project using the vue UI, and activated all ESLint rules avaible.

Got a few ESLint errors about whitespace, that was Easy to solve, but then it complained about the export row.

This is the script part of the Hello World:

```js
    import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'

    @Component
    export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
      @Prop() private msg!: string;
    }
```

And when running `npm run build` I get this error:

```
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
error: Expected the component literal to be directly exported (vue/require-direct-export) at src/components/HelloWorld.vue:141:1:
```

So how do I apply vue/require-direct-export on this simple export?
Tried commenting out parts of it but couldn't find a way that got accepted.

--- Edit 1 @Steven B. ---

```
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/recommended",
      "@vue/standard",
      "@vue/typescript"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser"
    },
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/__tests__/*.{j,t}s?(x)"
        ],
        "env": {
          "mocha": true
        }
      }
    ],
    "rules": {
      "vue/array-bracket-spacing": "error",
      "vue/arrow-spacing": "error",
      "vue/block-spacing": "error",
      "vue/brace-style": "error",
      "vue/camelcase": "error",
      "vue/comma-dangle": "error",
      "vue/component-name-in-template-casing": "error",
      "vue/eqeqeq": "error",
      "vue/key-spacing": "error",
      "vue/match-component-file-name": "error",
      "vue/no-boolean-default": "error",
      "vue/no-restricted-syntax": "error",
      "vue/object-curly-spacing": "error",
      "vue/require-direct-export": "error",
      "vue/script-indent": "error",
      "vue/space-infix-ops": "error",
      "vue/space-unary-ops": "error",
      "vue/v-on-function-call": "error"
    }
  },
```

Comment: Can you show us your `.eslintrc.js` file or your `eslintConfig` section in your `package.json`?

Comment: sure, the hole project is here: https://github.com/puggan/vue-test

Comment: I believe that the `require-direct-export` rule is not compatible with `vue-property-decorator` or with `Vue.extend`.  To save you a headache, I would turn it off.